# Can you install the Machine Learner front end on the same DAS/CEP instance

Tags: wso2, wso2-das, wso2-cep, wso2-ml

I'm currently testing out wso2 DAS and ML. The documentation for installing ML for DAS/CEP state to download the following features.

- Machine Learner Core
- Machine Learner Commons  Machine Learner
- Database Service
- ML Siddhi Extension

I assume the other machine learner features not listed are for the ML front end since I can not access the front end at https://192.168.34.1:9443/ml .

I did an experiment and installed the other ML features and was able to access the ML front end but I then ran in to exceptions/errors when I was using it.

Do I need to stand up ML separately from DAS to use the front end features of ML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that with the current version of WSO2 ML and WSO2 DAS, we can install and access ML's front-end feature in/from WSO2 DAS. We have already created a public JIRA for this issue [1] and once it is fixed we will notify you.

[1].   https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ML-311